Can't get NSTrackingArea enabledDuringMouseDrag to work
I'm trying to implement a right-click-and-drag operation to link two NSViews, in a very similar manner to creating constraints in the Xcode Interface Builder. I want the target NSView to respond to the drag on mouseEntered.
I've set up my tracking area as follows:
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        for trackingArea in self.trackingAreas {
            self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        }
        let tracking = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeInKeyWindow, .enabledDuringMouseDrag], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        self.addTrackingArea(tracking)
    }

The problem is that my mouseEntered isn't being called when you click-and-drag, though it is called fine when not dragging. Is there any way to make this work?
[edit] I have found I can force it to work by calling updateTrackingAreas() on any of my views during calls to rightMouseDragged(). This doesn't seem right though - what am I missing/misunderstanding?
[edit2] Apparently this may have been broken since macOS 13? https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724087

Do you draw a line like Xcode IB?

Yes, I draw a line between the two points while dragging.
